# What is the replacement of the Bash "source" command in the sh shell?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

What is replacement of the `source` command of bash shell in sh shell?

I was getting an error while executing source in `#!/bin/sh`.

In `#!/bin/bash`, it is working well.

Comment: To be pedantic, the question is really "What is the 'source' command a replacement of?", rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just dot command `.`

You can see more here: https://ss64.com/bash/source.html
and even here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)

Comment: Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 3):

`source` is a synonym for the [POSIX `.` (dot) command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). Note that `source`/`.` behaves slightly differently in `bash` than in the POSIX standard, but that difference comes from whether or not `bash` is run in POSIX mode, not in which name you use.

Comment: Thanks for reply!